# RuntimeException in Android when using BroadcastReceiver and My Application stop working

Tags: java, android

> Unable to start receiver br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.BroadcastReceiverAux: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> previously my app worked properly.but after adding

```
new getNewMessages().execute(new ApiConnector());
```

> code part it was giving a above run time error.
>
> logcat

```
09: W/dalvikvm(17914): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af49f0)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.BroadcastReceiverAux: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2126)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.BroadcastReceiverAux.onReceive(BroadcastReceiverAux.java:46)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2119)
08-07 17:53:30.609: E/AndroidRuntime(17914):    ... 10 more
08-07 17:53:31.249: W/System.err(17914): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "crowdeye.crowderia.com": No address associated with hostname
08-07 17:53:31.269: W/System.err(17914):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:467)
08-07 17:53:31.269: W/System.err(17914):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:258)
08-07 17:53:31.269: W/System.err(17914):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:236)
08-07 17:53:31.269: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
08-07 17:53:31.269: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.ApiConnector.getMessage(ApiConnector.java:31)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.getNewMessages.doInBackground(getNewMessages.java:14)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.getNewMessages.doInBackground(getNewMessages.java:1)
08-07 17:53:31.279: W/System.err(17914):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-07 17:53:31.289: W/System.err(17914):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-07 17:53:31.289: W/System.err(17914):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-07 17:53:31.289: W/System.err(17914):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-07 17:53:31.289: W/System.err(17914):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-07 17:53:31.289: W/System.err(17914):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-07 17:53:31.299: W/System.err(17914):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-07 17:53:31.299: W/System.err(17914): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
08-07 17:53:31.349: W/System.err(17914):    at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
08-07 17:53:31.349: W/System.err(17914):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
08-07 17:53:31.359: W/System.err(17914):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:452)
08-07 17:53:31.359: W/System.err(17914):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: is there any thing in your log like cause ? because you are getting a nullpointer

Comment: actually I didn't get your point.

Comment: ok post your whole logcat plz

Comment: I think problem with onReceive funtion

Comment: Please post complete logcat error output.

Comment: Does the async Task work normally when not called fro the receiver? Also, its bad practice to run an async task inside a broadcast receiver. You should put it into a service.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand the stack trace, or cannot understand how your code is triggering this crash, edit your question and post the stack trace.

Comment: I cannot upload my logcat.how can I do that

Comment: Add it to the question via copy/paste just like other code

Comment: what is code on line 46 of BroadcastReceiverAux.java

Comment: gerarNotificacao(context, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), "Nova mensagem",data.getTitle(),data.getShort_desc());
 }

Comment: data.getTitle(),data.getShort_desc() print them in log and check whether you are getting values or not

Comment: it surely will be. you are not setting Data data; variable to anything so you will get a NPE

Comment: thing is that to get those values I should run---->  new getNewMessages().execute(new ApiConnector());..but when I run that code I got this exceptions

Answer (score 1):

There may be other issues, but you need to add a period (`.`) to your receiver name `android:name="BroadcastReceiverAux"` should be receiver `android:name=".BroadcastReceiverAux"`. The reason is you're specifying a class name (and it is appended to your package name declared at the beginning of your manifest)

Take a look at the name part of [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

Comment: Both of those `android:name` values are equivalent.

Comment: That's my mistake then. I just recompiled one of my own apps to test this, I was so sure this didn't work!

Comment: For a bare class name, the leading `.` is optional. However, I think sub-packages are supported, and those require a leading `.`. So, given a `package` of `com.cardoso.awesomeapp`, a component named `com.cardoso.awesomeapp.Foo` could be written as `Foo`. But a component named ``com.cardoso.awesomeapp.bar.Goo` might need to be written either `.bar.Goo` or fully-qualified.